# NTRUEncrypt / NTRUSign source code?

Tags: ntruencrypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NTRUEncrypt source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026761/ntruencrypt-source-code)

Where would I find a NTRU implementation with sources? I know you can license it from the company that invented NTRU, but I just want to play with it at home.
Thanks