# NTRUEncrypt source code?

Tags: ntruencrypt, ntrusign

Can anybody point me to C or Java code (or anything else) that does NTRU encryption?

Several people who were implementing the algorithm have posted on this site, so maybe they could help?

I also noticed that quite a number of NTRU implementations have been written at universities, so it would seem strange that sources, or at least sample code, are so hard to come by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntru/

Answer (score 3):

The NTRU crypto is now available under an approved open source GPL v2 license.  You can find it here. 
https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto

Answer (score 2):

There is a post here: http://java.itags.org/java-programming/164200/

> You may find the tutorials on the NTRU
>   website helpful --
>   http://www.ntru.com/cryptolab is the
>   place to start.
>
> Note that we encourage people to
>   develop and play with the algorithms
>   themselves, but you may not distribute
>   your implementation without a license
>   from NTRU.
>
> ================================
>
> William Whyte, CTO, NTRU Cryptosystems

Perhaps this is why you cannot locate the source code, as you need a license.

Comment: I'm sure the NTRU company would like to be sent money every time somebody implements the algorithm. But things like ECC are patented out the wazoo and yet there are free implementations.
So I find it hard to believe that nobody, nowhere can release an open-source NTRUEncrypt implementation without being attacked by their lawyers.

Comment: Nothing stops lawyers from attacking.  They don't always win, but they'll always cheerfully attack on even the flimsiest of pretexts.

Comment: They now say it's okay if it's GPL.

Answer (score 2):

NTRU sources are also available from the FlexiProvider SVN repository:

```
svn co --username guest --password guest https://svn.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/svn/repos/flexiprovider
```

Answer (score 2):

Java sources for NTRUEncrypt and NTRUSign can be found here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntru/

Answer (score 2):

A command line interface for encryption and decryption using the NTRU cryptographic algorithm.

```
https://code.google.com/p/ntrutil/
```