# NTRUEncrypt C implementation

Tags: c, public-key-encryption, ntruencrypt

I can't find an NTRUEncrypt implementation in C, is it available as open source?

I want to implement this encryption in my kernel driver, is it possible?

Comment: What kind of kernel? Linux already has encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with William at Security Innovation, and just wanted to add that NTRU was recently open sourced, including our reference implementation in C. Java is soon to come. You can find the official repository on github, below:

https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto

Comment: That is great. Is there any python prototype for ntru?

Answer (score 1):

I work for Security Innovation, which owns NTRU. Contact me directly at wwhyte@securityinnovation.com and we'll see what we can do.

We're currently allowing non-commercial implementations of NTRU free of any licensing fee, but if you're planning to charge for your product we need to negotiate a license.

Comment: His product is not an encryption program, it's a kernel driver. That means that linking with a GPL product is allowed, if there is a distinguishable difference between the products. There is. What are you talking about exactly?

Comment: My comment above was posted before we made NTRU available under GPL. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I guess it's something I should have checked!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple listed in [NTRUEncrypt source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026761/ntruencrypt-source-code)

The accepted answer was

> Try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntru/