# Is there any NTRU alternative to GnuPG (either with (secure!) NTRUSign or different digital signature algorithm)?

Tags: security, digital-signature, elliptic-curve, ntrusign

I am looking for (potentially) more secure alternative to GnuPG (which is based on RSA and Elgamal). So I am curious if is there any working implementation of NTRU algorithms with same capabilities as GnuPG. I know that there is a lot of implementation of NTRUEncrypt (http://www.yassl.com/yaSSL/Products-cyassl.html, http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntru/ or answers here: [NTRUEncrypt source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026761/ntruencrypt-source-code/7378201#7378201)). I even found some implementation with NTRUSign (https://github.com/tbuktu/ntru), but they say that the NTRUSign was broken and should not be used (here is how it was broken http://www.di.ens.fr/~ducas/NTRUSign_Cryptanalysis/DucasNguyen_Learning.pdf), so as far I know, **there is no secure algorithm for NTRUSign**. (that analysis from 2012 includes "secure versions" of NTRUSign (like adding perturbations), the pure NTRUSign was broken in 2006)
**1) My first question is, am I wrong?**

Is there any secure (or not yet broken, which (I know) is  a significant difference). Or is there any secure Digital signature algorithm, which I may use for opensource without paying a lot for a licence and secure against bruteforce. I am mostly thinking of using ECDSA but I do not know how it is with patens and how secure is it. My second question: **2) Is there any secure digital signature other than DSA, ECDSA and RSA-PSS (and other RSA based), which would be good for signing messages?**  I know that there are others (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) but that is all I know about them.

And my third question **3) Is there any ECC implementation behaving similarly to GnuPG?** 
Ok, after I wrote the question I found this: https://code.google.com/p/gnupg-ecc/, so I will answer it right now. (Someone could find it useful)

And **4) Is there any other implementation of  asymetric encryption for both encrypting and signing as alternative to RSA,ElGamal,ECC?**

Comment: Putting many questions into one is a bad idea for SO. Though the question itself is very interesting, upvoted it.

Comment: Wikipedia states that NTRUSign is "broken" as of 2012, when just a couple of thousands of messages are enough to recover the private key.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I know about that but wikipedia is not always the best source (especially for recent informations) and especially if they are not telling anything about the second proposal to more secure NTRUSign (which was also broken in 2012). But thanks for reasuring me :)